# Redis server does not start after install in Docker

Tags: docker, redis

I'm using the official ubuntu image and installing redis via `apt-get install redis-server`

This all works fine, however redis doesn't start.  If I connect to the container and run `redis-server &` this will start redis in background.  I've tried adding `RUN redis-server &` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas how to get redis to start?

Comment: Any reason you are not using the official redis image? Either way, you are looking for [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) instead of `RUN`, which is only executed once during the build.

Comment: I'd argue it's simpler to use separate containers. Docker is designed for one process per container, running multiple processes is possible but requires a process manager like s6 or supervisord unless you want to get really hacky. Did you check [Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RUN redis-serve` only runs during docker build time.

You can use either  `CMD redis-server` or `ENTRYPOINT redis-server && bash` in your dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile) and simply change the first line to FROM ubuntu:latest or the specific version you need a run "docker build"